# How to extend the painting of a trackbar control?

Tags: c#, .net

This is driving me nuts. I am trying to label the ticks of a trackbar control. Therefore I want the control to use its base paint implementation, so I can add paint code to draw labels underneath every trackbar tick. I found an example that does basically the same thing. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13712/TimeSlider-A-time-based-TrackBar

What I do is the following :

```
public class DateTimeTrackBar : TrackBar
{
   :
   public DateTimeTrackBar()
   {
      :
      SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
   }

   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnPaint(e);

      base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, false);

      base.Refresh();                      // Use default paint implementation.

      // Adding additional paint code.
      if (ShowLabels)
         DrawLabels(e);                    // Works fine.

      base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }
    :
}
```

When the control comes up everything seems ok, but when I touches the trackbar thumb the control repaints itself and my labeling disappears. How is this possible ?

tia

Comment: I think I have seens this before. I looks a little like a Clip/Invalidate problem. Some Labels are still there other incomplete.. Hm ,soory I don't rember if and how I resolved it.. It is not restricted to using the thumb but also happens when using arrow keys to change the value.

Comment: TaW : if the control loses focus everything is painted ok.

Comment: The original code example is using the trick setting the UserPaint-Style to false, do a refresh and set it back again. So i think, first you don't have to call base.OnPaint. And second, if you want to call it, you should do it after SetStyle, may be after Refresh.

Comment: I already tried this to no avail.

Comment: _if the control loses focus everything is painted ok_ Indeed. I looked into the TrackBar [sources](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/TrackBar@cs/1305376/TrackBar@cs) but didn't see the reason; there are quite a few times when the do a `//The '1' in the call to SendMessage below indicates that the
                //trackbar should be redrawn (see TBM_SETRANGEMAX in MSDN)
                SendMessage(NativeMethods.TBM_SETRANGEMAX, 1, maximum);
                Invalidate(); ` - Call @Hans three times ;-)